# How to do (oauth-) role based access control for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, oauth

I am trying to implement a service with a public api which access control pattern is very similar to facebooks graph api. I am using the doorkeeper gem that allows me to do OAuth with Devise and also easily give permissions/scopes to access tokens.

So beyond that, I would need:
- access control based on the scope of the access token
- access control for different groups users on the platform (like privacy settings on facebook)
- access control has to be dynamic, cant assume fixed roles

No I did take a look at CanCan which seems to do role based access control, but it doesnt seem to incoorperate OAuth very easily, so that I ask myself whether it might be the best to just roll out my own system? Would it be the right way to basically do all the access control on the models then?

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What about CanCan does not serve your needs? I'm not familiar with OAuth, but I cannot think of a reason it would not work.

Comment: As far as I have seen from my research, CanCan is scoped for very traditional RBAC. I want dynamic scoping for potentially all users, so I can't put them in groups (at least thats my understanding of cancan)

Comment: I'm a little unsure about what is meant by "dynamic scoping."

Comment: Basically, a user should be able to decide who can see what data. As far as I understand CanCan you assign users a role, which is used to determine access to different attributes. Since there are likely tens of attributes over all n users, cancans approach doesnt seem to be appropriate

Comment: I think CanCan can do what you want, but how are the permissions determined. Given a user created model, how do you determine if a user can view it?

Comment: The user would complete his profile, and would then "answer" requests for his data with the attributes the application can access. So no static groups, or do I misunderstand CanCan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CanCan can handle what you want. Since you haven't provided specifics on what deems a user authorized, I will show you some methods I think will be helpful. The first thing I will say is that you can pass in any objects you want to your ability file. To do so, you do the following:

```
def ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_ability
    @current_ability = CustomAbility.new(pass, in, anything, here)
  end
end
```

In app/models you would when define custom_ability.rb:

```
def CustomAbility 
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(anything, you, want, here)
    ...
  end
end
```

In this case, anything = pass, you = in, want = anything, here = here. In addition, you can call some methods on the resource you are authorizing. CanCan works by loading @resource_name and then entering the ability file to authorize. It loads @resource_name by assuming RESTful routes, but you can easily use a before_filter to load your own resource, as long as you store it in @resource_name (i.e. store a User in @user).

You can also call certain methods on the object you are authorizing already created parameters. For instance, you may want to do something like this:

```
def initialize(user)
  can :read, Post do |post|
    !((post.readable_groups & user.groups).empty?)
  end
end
```

Basically, if a line in that block returns false then you become unauthorized. The only caveat is that the block is not executed on create or new. There are ways around this. For instance, lets say you enforced one post per user in the model level with uniqueness validations. You could use a before filter to load the post setting the user_id, and then do

```
can :create, Post, valid?: true
```

Anyway, hope that helps.

Comment: I guess the only question I would have is: How can I make certain attributes of Post visible depending on the arguments I pass to initialize? like i want admins to be able to see all data, but guests only view an excerpt of the post for example?

Comment: Normally, the actions in CanCan correspond to controller actions, although I do believe it is possible to arbitrarily define actions. For instance, I think you can put something like this: `can :read_part, Post # Hash or block of conditions here`, and then in your view you can say `<% if can?(:read_part, @post) %>`, etc.